# Specify sampling method in Metal Core Image Kernel

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, metalkit, ciimage

In Metal we can create samplers like this

```
      constexpr sampler s(coord::normalized, address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear);
```

Then we can sample any texture using this sampler.

I am wondering if something similar is available in Metal Core Image Kernels or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is! You can use a `CISampler` that you can pass to your kernel instead of a `CIImage`:

```
let sampler = CISampler(image: image, options: [
    kCISamplerWrapMode: kCISamplerWrapClamp,
    kCISamplerFilterMode: kCISamplerFilterLinear
])
```

You can also set `kCISamplerAffineMatrix` in the `options` to define a transform that is applied to the coordinates when sampling (`normalized` is the default behavior, I think).

Alternatively, you can use these convenience helpers on `CIImage` to set the wrap and filter modes:

```
// for linear & clamp-to-edge
let newImage = image.samplingLinear().clampedToExtent()
// for nearest & clamp-to-black (actually transparent, not black)
let newImage = image.samplingNearest().cropped(to: aRect)
```

Using these methods you can also force built-in filters to use the corresponding modes.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005484/metal-core-image-kernel-sampling) question. My doubts regarding samplers are growing!

Comment: Also another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005717/metal-core-image-kernel-use-of-dod) related to sampling. Please have a look.

Comment: Do you know how to convert existing Metal fragment shader to Core Image Kernel? If in Metal fragment shader we have interpolating vertex coordinate using which we sample all textures in the fragment shader, what is the equivalent in Core Image Kernel?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand... CI kernels are compute (not fragment) shaders. Pixel values will be interpolated between coordinates based on the sampler settings (linear or nearest).

Comment: I understand. What I am stuck in is accurately translating code written in Metal vertex/fragment shader to compute shader (CIKernel).

Comment: Also, CISampler passed to the kernel has infinite extent it seems. It is not the same as extent of the image used to create sampler.