# Metal Core Image Kernel use of DOD

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, cifilter

I wrote the following Metal Core Image Kernel to produce constant red color.

```
extern "C" float4 redKernel(coreimage::sampler inputImage, coreimage::destination dest)
{
  return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And then I have this in Swift code:

```
class CIMetalRedColorKernel: CIFilter {
  var inputImage:CIImage?
  
  static var kernel:CIKernel = { () -> CIKernel in
     let bundle = Bundle.main
     let url = bundle.url(forResource: "Kernels", withExtension: "ci.metallib")!
     let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
     return try! CIKernel(functionName: "redKernel", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
  }()

 override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
        return nil
    }

    let dod = inputImage.extent
    return CIMetalRedColorKernel.kernel.apply(extent: dod, roiCallback: { index, rect in
        return rect
    }, arguments: [inputImage])
 }
}
```

As you can see, the dod is given to be the extent of the input image. But when I run the filter, I get a whole red image beyond the extent of the input image (DOD), why? I have multiple filters chained together and the overall size is 1920x1080. Isn't the red filter supposed to run only for DOD rectangle passed in it and produce clear pixels for anything outside the DOD?

Answer (score 1):

With the `extent` parameter of the kernel call you signal the region for which the kernel produces meaningful results—or, as you correctly named it, the *domain of definition*.
However, this also means that whatever it produces outside this region is basically undefined and up to you as the kernel developer to decide.

A generator kernel like the one you wrote usually has an *infinite* domain of definition since it just produces a red color, regardless of the input. To restrict the output to a specific area, you can apply a crop to it:

```
let dod = inputImage.extent
let result = CIMetalTestRenderer.kernel.apply(extent: .infinite, roiCallback: { index, rect in
    return rect
}, arguments: [inputImage])
return result.cropped(to: dod)
```

After the cropping, everything outside of `dod` will be transparent.

---

**Update:**

It turns out you have to set the `extent` parameter of the kernel call to `.infinite` to make this work. I suspect that `cropped(to:)` checks if the image already has the given extent and will do nothing in this case. So to make CI really apply the cropping, you have to specify the domain of definition your kernel actually produces.

I think the counter-intuitive thing here is that CI does not apply your kernel to *just* the pixels of the `extent` you specify. It seems there is some automatic clamp-to-extent going on when the result is not cropped properly, but honestly, I'm also rather confused by this...

Comment: I was hoping that the shader does not execute anything outside it's domain of definition. But it seems to execute on every possible pixel (just like infinite extent). That raises the question -- how is the region of computation to execute shaders decided?

Comment: Basically by the destination. Every pixel in the destination needs to be produced and for that Core Image goes up the filter chain. You can use `cropped(to:)` to tell CI that it should not execute your kernel for pixels outside of that region.

Comment: What I fail to understand is then what is the use of extent parameter? The documentation for extent parameter reads - "The extent of the output image."....cropped(to:) would also achieve the same result as setting the extent of the output image.

Comment: Update: cropped(to:) also gives same result, no change! Let me know if you need sample project (code is already posted anyways but for convenience just let me know).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dsharma/CoreImagePrototypes.git) is sample code for your reference. Feel free to play with it and make suggestions. If there is any issue downloading the code, let me know.

Comment: I see removing the sourceover compositing with cyan color background gives *almost* correct results.  Try it in the source code.  Not sure what is wrong with source over filter.

Comment: Updated. I'm also a bit confused by this behavior. It seems sometimes avoiding a clamp-to-extent behavior needs to be done rather deliberately. ‍♂️

Comment: It seems the DOD is the largest extent rectangle in the filter chain, that is the behavior. I will shoot an email to DTS for technical support.